# SLDS class for different opportunity stages

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

I am looking out for slds classes for different opportunity stages.
Specifically I'm looking for class which shows 'closed won' stage
[image]

And closed lost stage like below

[image]

The class below I'm using is

```
'slds-path__item   slds-is-complete';
```

But it shows only green background like below
[image]

Can anyone help me how I can get same effect like standard opportunity guided path has for closed won and closed lost

Answer (score 1):

Use the below classes for each stage:

Stage Won Classes - `slds-is-active slds-is-current slds-is-won slds-path__item`
[image]

Stage Lost Classes - `slds-path__item slds-is-lost slds-is-active slds-is-current`

[image]

Happy learning

Answer (score 0):

Try `slds-path__title`

```
<span class="slds-path__title">Closed Won</span>
```

More information [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/path/).

Comment: This doesn't give exact requirement I'm looking for. I'm looking for one with text and green background and one with text and red background